# How to make string concatenation work with Nashorn's JSObject

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

### Intention

I'm using Java 8u60 (**not** 8u51, this is important!) and am working with its Nashorn JavaScript engine. I created my own `JSObject` by extending `AbstractJSObject`. It's supposed to wrap an `org.json.JSONObject` and make it work like an actual JavaScript object in the script engine. Given that `javaAPI` is a Java object that was put into the `ScriptContext`, the resulting object should be usable like this:

```
var jsonObject = javaAPI.doSomethingThatReturnsAJSONObject();
var foo = jsonObject.foo
jsonObject.foo = "bar";
delete jsonObject.foo;
var message = "JSON: " + jsonObject;
```

### Code

```
public class JSONObjectJavaScriptAdapter extends AbstractJSObject {

    private final JSONObject jsonObject;

    public JSONObjectJavaScriptAdapter(final JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeMember(String name) {
        jsonObject.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMember(String name, Object value) {
        jsonObject.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return jsonObject.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMember(String name) {
        return jsonObject.has(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getMember(String name) {
        return jsonObject.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

### Problem

Everything works fine except for the string concatenation. Writing something like

```
var message = "JSON: " + jsonObject;
```

will result in the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["valueOf"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:476)
    at my.JSONObjectJavaScriptAdapter.getMember(JSONObjectJavaScriptAdapter.java:50)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.DefaultValueImpl.getDefaultValue(DefaultValueImpl.java:42)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject.getDefaultValue(AbstractJSObject.java:269)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject.getDefaultValue(AbstractJSObject.java:285)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toPrimitive(JSType.java:512)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toPrimitive(JSType.java:480)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toPrimitive(JSType.java:462)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.ADD(ScriptRuntime.java:563)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$2$16$configuration.main(src/test/resources/de/ams/inm/workflow/engine/javascript/async/configuration.js:23)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:383)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
    [...]
```

What do I need to do to make Nashorn call the `toString()` method so that `message` will contain something like `JSON: {"foo":"bar}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

It turns out that Nashorn follows the ECMA specification to the letter. The important parts are [The Addition operator ( + )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) and [[[DefaultValue]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8).

If the + operator is used for objects, those objects will be converted to primitives using the [[DefaultValue]] function. The default [[DefaultValue]] implementation converts objects to primitives by using either the `valueOf` or the `toString` function.

Objects may override the [[DefaultValue]] function to provide a custom to-primitive conversion. Since Java 8u60 this is also possibly in Nashorn, by overriding `AbstractJSObject.getDefaultValue(Class)`.

I added the following code to `JSONObjectJavaScriptAdapter` to make the string concatenation work as excepted:

```
@Override
public Object getDefaultValue(Class<?> hint) {
    return toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if JSObject.getMember could handle any exception thrown and perhaps return null or appropriate value - rather than propagating exception. In your example, org.json.JSONObject.get throws Exception when a property is not found.

Another thing: you could return a 'function value' for 'toString' or 'valueOf' property - so that it gets called for toString/toNumber conversions as specified in ECMAScript.

Comment: You're right, I should catch exceptions in `getMember(String)`. I know about the 'function value' though, but I think overriding `getDefaultValue(Class)` is much simpler in the context of Nashorn.